# Ping is not happening between PCs

Tags: ping, gigabit-ethernet

I have designed custom Embedded system with two **RGMII ports** which works in Linux OS.

**One of the port is pinging with the PC while other is not**. All the Configurations of both ETHo ports are same.
Hardware side seems no issue.

I'm not using the any router in between. Also I changed the domain and tried but still not working.

What could be the issue. Any mistake in configurations?
Looking for valuable suggestions.

-thanks and regards,

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to Ping?

What i gather is you have two pcs directly connected? is that correct?

If it is one machine to another, are both machines ip addresses configured to be in the same subnet?

EG: If computer ones IP is 192.168.70.2 then Computer twos IP has to start the same, 192.168.70.x

Since you are not using a Router i assume you do not have a Domain, make sure you network "Workgroups" are the same.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/join-create-workgroup

Have you tried using DHCP on both machines? this way it will automatically configure your settings, Then test if you can ping across machines,if you can ping successfully, you have not configured your machine correctly.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/change-tcp-ip-settings

Can you post the configurations you are using?

Cheers

Ryan